Xamarin iOS System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied reading shared files
System.UnauthorizedAccessException is triggered in our Xamarin iOS app when reading a shared file, either from another app or through a public folder.
This error is new and started after updating from VS2019 to VS2022 (Windows). There were also a number of macOS updates (now Ventura 13.7). The sharing code works fine but there seems to be a security setting missing - hopefuly a simple oversight.
Below are snippets from the app. Any suggestions on where to start looking for the cause?
info.plist:
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
    <string>Public plain-text</string>
    <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string>public.plain-text</string>
    </array>
</dict>

AppDelegate.cs:
public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication app, NSUrl url, NSDictionary options)
{
    MyModule mm = new MyModule();
    mm.AddFile(url.Path);
    return true;
}

MyModule.cs:
public class MyModule
{
    public void AddFile(string url)
    {
        ...
        var text = File.ReadAllText(url); << Exception line >>
        ...
    }
}

Exception message:
{System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/File Provider Storage/xxxxx.txt" is denied.
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x0026e] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:274 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:106 
  at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor (System.String path, System.Text.Encoding encoding, System.Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, System.Int32 bufferSize) [0x00055] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/IO/StreamReader.cs:182 
  at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor (System.String path, System.Text.Encoding encoding, System.Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/IO/StreamReader.cs:167 
  at System.IO.File.InternalReadAllText (System.String path, System.Text.Encoding encoding) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/external/corefx/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/File.cs:303 
  at System.IO.File.ReadAllText (System.String path) [0x00026] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/external/corefx/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/File.cs:282 
  at [App].MyModule.AddFile (System.String fullPath) [0x00002] in C:\xxxx\...\xxxx.cs:187 }


How do you generate the url for the file?

The share icon on the file to be shared is used, then electing our app's icon from the list. The event passes the url to the OpenUrl handler.
